# creating lists in single scan

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create 2 lists from one column based on condition in other column. Currently, I am able to get the 2 lists by scaning dataframe twice.

1. Is it possible to get the 2 lists in single scan?
2. Getting lists by individual groups?

```
data = {
    "co2": [95, 90, 99, 104, 105, 94, 99, 104],
    "model": [
        "Citigo",
        "Fabia",
        "Fiesta",
        "Rapid",
        "Focus",
        "Mondeo",
        "Octavia",
        "B-Max",
    ],
    "car": ["Skoda", "Skoda", "Ford", "Skoda", "Ford", "Ford", "BMW", "Ford"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# For 2 lists
list_skoda = df.loc[df["car"] == "Skoda", "model"].tolist()
print(f"{list_skoda=}")

list_others = df.loc[df["car"] != "Skoda", "model"].tolist()
print(f"{list_others=}")

# For individual groups
df.groupby(["car"]).apply(print)
l = df.groupby(["car"])["model"].groups

print(f"{l=}") # This gives indices not names
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want in one statement by grouping on whether the `car` value is `Skoda` or not:

```py
m = df["car"] == "Skoda"
list_others, list_skoda = df['model'].groupby(m).agg(list).to_list()
print(list_skoda, list_others, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
['Citigo', 'Fabia', 'Rapid']
['Fiesta', 'Focus', 'Mondeo', 'Octavia', 'B-Max']
```